# loop through to add a variable to a JSON array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I want to add a new variable (score) to my JSON array. The database has the number of 1st points, 2nd points and 3rd points each member has received and I want to calculate the total score for each member and display the top ten for the selected team. This is the code I have to add the $score to the JSON however it only adds it onto the end of the array and not for each member.

```
$result[] = $res->fetchAll();  
$result[] = array('score' => $score);  
echo json_encode($result);
```

And I have an if statement that depends on which radio button a user presses. This is how I calculate the score:

```
if($redTeam == true){
$score = (($no_first_points + $no_scnd_points + $no_third_points)/$redMembers);
}

else if($blueTeam == true){
$score = (($no_first_points + $no_scnd_points + $no_third_points)/$blueMembers);
}
```

If I echo out the JSON array currently I get this:

```
{
    "no_first_points": "10",
    "no_scnd_points": "25",
    "no_third_points": "15",
    "redMembers": "125",
    "blueMembers": "1‌​25",
    "team_name": "Blue"
}, {
    "no_first_points": "20",
    "no_scnd_points": "17",
    "no_third_points": "27",
    "redMembers": "125",
    "blueMembers": "1‌​25",
    "team_name": "Red"
}, {
    "score": "40"
}
```

However I want each team to have the correct score in the same array like this:

```
{
    "no_first_points": "10",
    "no_scnd_points": "25",
    "no_third_points": "15",
    "members": "125",
    "blueMembers": "1‌​25",
    "team_name": "Tigers",
    "score": "40"
}, {
    "no_first_points": "20",
    "no_scnd_points": "17",
    "no_third_points": "27",
    "redMembers": "125",
    "blueMembers": "1‌​25",
    "team_name": "Pumas",
    "score": "45"
}
```

I have 200 members in total from both teams that need to be assigned a score and then I want to display the top ten from the team selected. So if the Blue Team radio button is selected, the top ten blue members would be shown with their score.

Comment: you don't work with a "json array". no such thing. there's a JSON string. You deal with a NATIVE data structure, then use json_encode/json_decode to convert to/from json once you're done.

Comment: @MarcB I am using json_encode

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$result = $res->fetchAll();  
$result['score'] = $score;  
echo json_encode($result);
```

UPDATE:

```
$result = $res->fetchAll();  
foreach($result as $key => $entry)
    $result[$key]['score'] = $score;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: again all this did was {"score":0}

Comment: @Raynor Does `fetchAll` return correct result?

Comment: fetchAll brings back all the correct data

Comment: @Raynor `array("no_first_points" => "10","no_scnd_points" => "25","no_third_points" => "15","redMembers" => "125","blueMembers" => "1‌​25","team_name" =>"Blue")` this data?

Comment: Yes all of that data, and when I added $result = $res->fetchAll();  
$result['score'] = $score;  echo json_encode($result); It just returned {"score":0} with the other data

Comment: @Raynor Check `$result` with `var_dump($result)` after `$result = $res->fetchAll();`

Comment: array(200) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["no_first_points"]=>
    string(1) "10"
    ["no_scnd_points"]=>
    string(1) "25"
    ["no_third_points"]=>
    string(1) "15"
    ["redMembers"]=>
    string(11) "125"
    ["blueMembers"]=>
    string(7) "125"
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(7) "Blue"
  } and so on...

Comment: So your *fetchAll* function returns array in array. So use $result = $res->fetchAll(); $result = $result[0];

Comment: That worked for the first one but how would I use if I wanted to do the other 199?

Comment: That did not work, that didn't add the score for some reason

Comment: @Raynor Look, I corrected, it should work fine

Comment: That adds a score to each, however its the same score for each one which isn't right

Comment: @Raynor So add your score calculation function in the foreach loop

Comment: @Raynor `$score = (($entry['no_first_points'] + $entry['no_scnd_points'] + $entry['no_third_points'])/$entry['redMembers']);`

Comment: Like this: $result = $res->fetchAll();  
foreach($result as $key => $entry)
if($redTeam == true){
$score = (($no_first_points + $no_scnd_points + $no_third_points)/$redMembers);
$result[$key]['score'] = $score;
}
echo json_encode($result);?

Comment: @Raynor Like `$result = $res->fetchAll(); foreach($result as $key => $entry) if($redTeam == true){ $score = (($entry['no_first_points'] + $entry['no_scnd_points'] + $entry['no_third_points'])/$entry['redMembers']); $result[$key]['score'] = $score; } echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: get this 'Warning: Division by zero'

Comment: Somewhere redMembers equals 0

Comment: every team has more than zero members, I did an sql query to check this

Comment: that is because in your array there are blue and red teams together and redMembers field is not in every subarray

Comment: some members have zero points, but this wouldn't be divided by zero it would be 0/redMembers

Comment: I removed the divide out of the formula to check and every persons score is zero